# How to use slash in hash arrays in bash?

Tags: bash

I'm going to save all docker tags using code below

```
set -x
registry="docker.my-registry.com"
repos=getRepos
declare -A allTags
for repo in $repos; do
   echo $registry/$repo
   tags=getTags
   allTags["$registry$repo"]=$tags
done
```

But got error `syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".my-registry.comimageName")`

How to use slash in bash arrays?

Comment: You can't have spaces around the `=` in shell assignments. With the space, it thinks that `allTags[docker.my-registry.com/imageName]` is the name of a program to run, and `= $tags` are the arguments.

Comment: `set-x` should be `set -x`

Comment: Why did you think the problem was due to the slash? You get the same problem if you use `allTags["$registry$repo"]`, don't you?

Comment: @Barmar now I get syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator

Comment: Alex, update your question with your current code, and error

Comment: Where is `imageName` coming from? You assigned `repos=getRepos`, not `repos=imageName`

Comment: Are you sure you used `declare -A` and not `declare -a`? The latter makes it an ordinary array, and then indexes are treated as arithmetic expressions.

Comment: getRepos and getTags just function for example, actually there url fetching and json parsing. 
declare -a doesnt help, looks like it try to execute "$registry$repo" like expression

Comment: @AlexKlimashevsky : Actually, in the code you posted, `getRepos` is simply a string; no function execution involved. If you really have a function of this name, you don't invoke it anywhere. I also can not reproduce your error message. Please copy&paste the output of the execution (due to your usage of `set -x`, it should be obvious then what's going wrong).